# create master detail with linq for devexpress grid control

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grid, devexpress

How can I make a relation between two list an show them in a grid with master detail. 
I wrote this but it didn't work:

```
        var students = (from s in new XPQuery<StudentOfClass>(session)
                       join e in new XPQuery<Exam>(session) on s equals e.StudentOfClass
                       select new
                       {
                           LastName = s.Student.LastName,
                           Score = e.Score,
                           Grade = e.GradeTitle,
                           Class = s.Class,
                       }).ToList();
        var classes = (from c in new XPQuery<Class>(session)
                      select new
                      {
                          Class = c,
                          StudentsOfClass = students.Where(x=>x.Class == c),
                      }).ToList();
        gcClass.DataSource = classes;
```

and also I've added a level to my grid and named it "StudentsOfClass"

I've got error for where clause.

Comment: If this link could help https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q368027

Answer (score 0):

write the code like

```
var classes = from c in new XPQuery<Class>(session)
    select new Class
    {
        Class = c,
        Student = students,
    };
```

and create the grid coloumn same as all the coloumn of the list